# Can I use Visual Studio 2012 to develop a Windows 8 Metro application?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-express

I have Visual Studio 2012.  I see, however, the Microsoft is promoting Visual Studio Express 2012 for writing Windows 8 Metro applications:

"You have an idea for an app that could change lives around the world. Visual Studio Express for Windows 8 delivers everything you need to bring it to millions of customers. And those changed lives we were talking about? One of them could be yours."

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-8

I know the express versions of Visual Studio are free.  I'd prefer, however, to use my bought and paid for VS 2012 rather than installing the express version.

Is there anything in "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8" that is not in "Visual Studio 2012" for developing Windows 8 Metro  Applications? I realize that this is a simple question, but I can't find the answer on Microsoft web pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create **Modern UI** applications, formerly known as **Metro UI** applications in Visual Studio 2012. Thus, every application that you create with Express should be availiable in full version (Professional, Ultimate, etc.) versions of Visual Studio.

Here is a comparison diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The Express editions are a subset of the full Visual Studio and you can create "Windows Store" applications (formerly called Metro) with the full VS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

From [VS Express download link](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-8)

> Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 provides the core tools that are required to build compelling, innovative Windows Store apps.